# What will be the value of ψ

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Given that $\nabla^2\phi$=0,the solution of $\nabla^2ψ$=k$(\nabla\phi)$.$(\nabla\phi)$
 first i started with the given condition, since i know that the divergence of the curl is zero so i can write the condition as$$\nabla.(\nabla\phi)=0$$ 
 which implies that $(\nabla\phi)$=$(\nabla*A)$ then i put this into the above given equation and got $$\nabla^2ψ=k(\nabla*A).(\nabla*A)$$
 after this i got stuck now how to proceed?

Comment: What's the dimension of your problem?

Comment: I take your question as you want to know the unit of ψ. Actually in the question no dimension was given but i think it should be of  k as the dot product of ∇ϕ will give a scalar so we will be left with the only dimension of k.

Answer (score 1):

here we will first look at $\nabla^2\phi=0$ we can write this as $$\nabla.(\nabla\phi)=0$$
 so we can write $\phi=$ $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z$ and now if we substitute $\nabla\phi=0$ in the given equation then we can write  $$\nabla^2ψ = k ( \alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2$$
 now let us assume that $ψ$=$\frac{k\phi^2}{2}$ is the solution. Then on substituting this solution in the given equation we get the above result hence the solution is $$ψ=\frac{k\phi^2}{2}$$